# How to write script alert in response.redirect on button click in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have written following code in asp.net . It gives error like Bad request.
Code as follows

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        // some code
 Response.Redirect("<script>alert('Successfully Added!');window.location ='../Admin/frmStateMgmt.aspx';</script>");  // It gives error here.
}
```

Comment: WOW.You are magician you have written new implementation of Response.Redirect. Please check what parameters Response.Redirect takes.

Comment: Thnk U , but what i have written is some1 told m to write this line..I'm learner of asp.net. But thnks for ur help .@MairajAhmad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.Redirect` does not take script as parameter it takes url of page on which you want to go.

```
 Response.Redirect("somepage.aspx");
```

If you need to alert something you can do by this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "SomeKey", "alert('Some alert')", true);
```

Comment: Thnks for help@MairajAhmad

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer ,

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         //some code
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
            Response.Write("alert('Successfully Added!');");
            Response.Write("document.location.href='../Admin/frmStateMgmt.aspx';");
            Response.Write("</script>");
}
```

I have got answer by using Reponse.Write. Hope some 1 would get help.